# To "close the circle" or not to "close the circle"...?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

For my thesis title, I'm thinking of using a phrase that underlines the work I do, which is to *bridge* the beginning and end of a workflow, to create a perpetual analytical process.

To give a bit more context; I do my research in the last steps of a long workflow that involves many steps from hypothesis, experiment design, experimentation and a large number of processing steps. The goal of my work has been to facilitate interpretation of the data, extraction of insights and hopefully to formulate new hypotheses, thus providing a feedback loop.

My first idea was to write "*Closing the circle*", however the phrase can also be understood as a way to "end" things, or to signify that nothing has been gained or no progress was made, like "*back to square 1"*.

I like the "circle" idea since a circle has no beginning and no end, but I don't want to give the impression of a lack of progress.

Any thoughts on that? If my understanding of the phrase "*closing the circle*" is correct, are there any synonyms that could fit? Otherwise, what phrase would be better fit?

Comment: You could say "completing the circle", of course, but by far the most common idiom in play is "closing the loop" (to the extent that it has become cliche).

Comment: You might consider "squaring the circle", an idiom which can mean "making sense of what's happened" (although some dictionaries don't include that meaning).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, erm, that's not what I understand squaring the circle to mean...

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not sure the term ["squaring the circle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle#In_literature) portrays right image, especially if it has intonations of "futility" or "utopia".

Comment: Suggest using 'join the loop', which implies continuation.